# How to get a value from text box in form 1 to another

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I have a form witch is a calculator i want to post the answer of calculator to form2
When i click the button post it show next form but it can not post the value

```
Private Sub cmdpost_Click()
Me.TXTnumber.Copy
UserForm2.Show
UserForm2.TextBox3.Paste
Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that you can't change the event name from "UserForm_Click" to "cmdpost_Click". Am I right? Is your code running?

Comment: please  explain about 'Me.TXTnumber.Copy'. what is the txtnumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason to Copy Paste these?

If TXTnumber is a named textbox won't this work for you?

```
UserForm2.TextBox3 = Me.TXTnumber
UserForm2.Show
```